# How to save the Black Pixels of a grayscale image and draw it to another graysclae image of same size?

Tags: c++, opencv, contour

I am trying to save the Black pixel positions of an original grayscale image and later want to draw it to the modified version of the grayscale image. And My code is here:

```
std::vector< std::vector <cv::Point> > Black_Pixel;
    for(int y = 0; y < Original_Image.rows; y++)
        {
            for(int x = 0; x < Original_Image.cols; x++)
                {               
                    if (Original_Image.at<unsigned char>(x,y) == 0 )
                        {
                             Black_Pixel[0].push_back(cv::Point(x,y));
                             Black_Pixel.push_back( std::vector <cv::Point>());
                         }                                      
                }
        }

    for( unsigned int idx = 0; idx < Black_Pixel.size(); idx++ )
        {
            New_image.at<unsigned char>(Black_Pixel[0][idx].x,Black_Pixel[0][idx].y) = 0;
            cv::waitKey();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
row.push_back(cv::Point(x,y));

Actually, take away row, and instead have this:

```
Black_Pixel[0].push_back(cv::Point(x,y));
```

of course you first need to initialize the 0th element in Black_Pixel:

```
Black_Pixel.push_back(std::vector<cv::Point>);
```

Comment: which variable will be here : Black_Pixel.push_back(std::vector<cv::Point>??);     Because its showing compilation error

Comment: try Black_Pixel.push_back(std::vector<cv::Point>()); then. Does that work? 
It will create a blank zeroeth element in BlackPixel, since it is array, you cannot access a variable - it's subarray - before you actually create the element.

Comment: I am getting segmentation fault And do you think cv::drawContours is the right function to draw the Black Pixels to another image matrix??

Comment: Depends if these black pixels signify contour verteces... which is a bit confusing, the way you've stated the program, you seem to need that isntead of drawContours:

New_Image.at<unsigned char>(Black_Pixel[0][idx].x,Black_Pixel[0][idx].y) = 0;

Comment: :The black pixels are background pixel of the grayscale image and I only need there position so that I can draw it in the same position of the original image to the modified version

Comment: @perfanfoff: I get a segmentation fault in the first line Black_Pixel[0].push_back(cv::Point(x,y));

Comment: Black_Pixel.push_back(std::vector<cv::Point>()); << you need this right after declaration so that you HAVE a Black_Pixel[0] element!

Comment: ok I am additing the code with your suggestion.Maybe I am missing something

Comment: And I have also tried both lines in the 2nd loop. But it still giving the segmentation fault in the first line.

Comment: Black_Pixel.push_back(std::vector<cv::Point>()); << move that right after declaring Black_Pixel -> after the very first line of code in your snippet

Comment: Now its not giving any compilation error but the code is not doing any thing.

Comment: now get rid of the cvWaitKey, it may make you have to press enter for each single black pixel that is painted, if you have any windows open.

Comment: it doesn't bother me though.I have removed it and no improvement.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::vector <cv::Point> Black_Pixel;
for(int y = 0; y < Original_Image.cols; y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < Original_Image.rows; x++)
            {               
                if (Original_Image.at<unsigned char>(x,y) == 0 )
                    {
                         Black_Pixel.push_back(cv::Point(x,y));
                    }                                      
            }
    }

for( unsigned int idx = 0; idx < Black_Pixel.size(); idx++ )
    {
        New_image.at<unsigned char>(Black_Pixel[idx]) = 0;           
    }

cv::imshow("New Image", New_image);
```